# 'Connection reset by peer' error when installing Solana CLI on WSL

Tags: solana-cli

I receive the following error when installing Solana on WSL:

```
$ curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/stable/install | sh
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to release.solana.com:443
```

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows11，I don't understand why this problem keeps appearing.

Comment: I used wsl system.

Comment: Hi @aaak. This is a general networking issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434451/what-does-connection-reset-by-peer-mean

Comment: BTW - does Windows have a VPN on? https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4698 . But again, this is a Windows / WSL2 issue not a Solana issue.

Comment: You should also check out this comment from Microsoft - https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4698#issuecomment-1726513542

Answer (score -1):

Can you try installing dependencies before trying to install solana in WSL?

```
sudo apt-get install -y \
build-essential \
pkg-config \
libudev-dev llvm libclang-dev \
protobuf-compiler libssl-dev
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: bro, sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/stable/install)"
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to release.solana.com:443

Comment: can you tell what's the output when you try

```wsl -l -v```

in your terminal?

Comment: `Connection reset by peer` is a networking issue. There is nothing about the error that indicates there are missing dependencies.